# get attribute value in PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How to validate the value inside input field using PAF tag? I tried several methods which was a failure.

> Google says we have **getAttribute()** function in Selenium. What is
> the alternative for the above function in PAF?

Answer (score 0):

In PAF, 
we have **variable tag** and **validate tag** to illustrate this scenario. For example;

```
<variable xpath="" keyName="" webElementAttr="" ></variable>
```

webElementAttr="attribute" will capture attribute value of a web element

```
<valGroup groupId="">
          <validate xpath="" exists="true" type="text"</validate>
</valGroup>
```

If you do not find an attribute name while inspecting, Try the below steps:

```
<activities>

            <activity id="fillFormDetails">

                              <input id="userNumber" value="00900700999"/>
                              <dblClick id="userNumber" />
                              <specialKeys xpath="//input[@id='userNumber']" specialChar="{control}+a"></specialKeys>
                              <specialKeys xpath="//input[@id='userNumber']" specialChar="{control}+c"></specialKeys>
                              <clipboard varName="varA"></clipboard>
                              <input id="currentAddress" value="${varA}"/>

             </activity>

</activities>
```

Then validate variable name called ' varA '.